# UiPickerView change font color according data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using a pickerView with multiple components related to several fields in a Database (CoreData).
Is it possible to change the fontcolor for a specific component according the presence of data in the DB ?
For example the field in the DB is null the component font color should be RED otherwise black.

Any help will be appreciated !

Dario

==================
Thanks Kenny,

I have to apply to a single UIPicker only. So I', returning the view parametere (without modificatiosn). The result is all the pickers show empty rows.

Thanks for help !

Here you will find the code fragment:

```
  - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

if (pickerView == tipoPk){
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100,30)];
label.textColor =      [UIColor redColor];
switch (component) {
case PK_Tipo:
label.text =  [tipoArray objectAtIndex:row]];
break;
case PK_Settore:
label.text =  [settoreArray objectAtIndex:row]];
break;
default:
break;
}
return label;
}
else {
return view;    // <====   return view for non related pickerviews , but no rows shown
}  


}
```

Answer (score 4):

This one also works..

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 15, 15);
UIImageView *label = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame] **autorelease**];

if (row == 0)
{
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
if (row == 1)
{
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
if (row == 2)
{
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}   
return label;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to use `-pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` and supply a custom UILabel.