# how to change font size of date picker view and picker view in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, uipickerview

I want to change font size of date picker and picker view. is this possible ?
if is it? then how it done.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UiPickerView change font color according data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850234/uipickerview-change-font-color-according-data)

Answer (score 1):

There is no any API for change apperiance of `UIDatePicker`.

You can make a pretty convincing replica yourself using a `UIPickerView`

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
return a;}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return b;}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

UILabel *lblpkr= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(p,q,r,s)];
[lblpkr setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lblpkr setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[lblpkr setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:x]];
[lblpkr setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",row]];

return lblpkr;}
```

**For Swift**

See this for customizable implementation of `UIDatePicker`

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/PIDatePicker

Answer (score 0):

No you can't customise `UIDatepicker`, as per given on [apple's Official site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIDatePicker-SW3).

So Developer has no rights to change UIDatepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can update the font size using method swizzling. This is how I change the font

```
#import "UILabel+Extra.h"

@implementation UILabel (Extra)

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSArray *arrayFont = [self.font.fontName componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSArray *arrayRobotoStyleName = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Roboto"];
    __block NSString *style;
    if(arrayFont.count >= 2){
        [arrayRobotoStyleName enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL * _Nonnull stop){
            NSString *styleName = [arrayFont lastObject];
            if ([obj containsString:styleName]){
                style = styleName;
                *stop = TRUE;
            }
            else if (index == ([arrayRobotoStyleName count] - 1)){
                style = @"Regular";
                *stop = TRUE;
            }
        }];
    }
    else
        style = @"Regular";

    if (!style) {
        style = @"Regular";
    }
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Roboto-%@",style] size:self.font.pointSize];
}

-(void)setAppearanceFont:(UIFont *)font{
    if (font)
        [self setFont:font];
}

-(UIFont *)appearanceFont{
    return self.font;
}
```