# Increase font size of date picker in iOS(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, datepicker

I have gone through many documentation, but i didn't find this thing anywhere.

how to increase font size of date picker in Swift.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678487/how-to-change-font-size-of-date-picker-view-and-picker-view-in-ios-objective-c

Comment: this is for picker view @Kuldeep

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change font size of date picker view and picker view in iOS Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678487/how-to-change-font-size-of-date-picker-view-and-picker-view-in-ios-objective-c)

Comment: No, you can't change the font size of date picker, anyhow there is workaround to change the selected cell size, if you are insterested https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DatePicker/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

Comment: all those documents are there in Objective C @JigarTarsariya @ Vinaykrishnan

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be too hard to make the transfer from Objective C to Swift, I really recommend you should give it a try! If you have problems, post your swift code, and we will be pleased to help you.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't change the font size of UIDatePicker.**

If you want to have the customized version of UIDatePicker, you might find some third party library which might provide you similar behaviour as UIDatePicker. But I won't recommend it if the font size is the only concern you have.

Answer (score -1):

> Appearance
>
> The appearance of UIDatePicker is not customizable.
>
> You should integrate date pickers in your layout using Auto Layout.
>   Although date pickers can be resized, they should be used at their
>   intrinsic content size.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker

Comment: You can change the font size for sure, just check the duplicate links. All you'll have to do is to return a custom view in the delegate method `pickerView(_:viewForRow:forComponent:reusing:)`

Comment: @AndreasOetjen The question was about UIDatePicker which does not inherit from UIPickerView and is not relevant to the delegate method you cited.