# How can I change DatePicker font weight in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, datepicker, swiftui, font-size

I've tried below code. But `.font` function does not change anything. I want to the date more darker. How can I do that?

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            DatePicker("", selection: $date, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
                .padding()
                .labelsHidden()
                .accentColor(.red)
                .font(Font.body.weight(.bold))
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810977/increase-font-size-of-date-picker-in-iosswift

Comment: and also I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678487/how-to-change-font-size-of-date-picker-view-and-picker-view-in-ios-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

While you can't specifically change the text for the DatePicker, you can use and HStack to accomplish the desired outcome.

```
    HStack {
             Text("End Date")
                   .font(.custom((Fonts.gse), size: 18))
                   .fontWeight(.medium)
             Spacer()
             DatePicker("", selection: self.$endingDate, in: self.dateRange, displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
}
```

Comment: no need to use HStack you can pass the label as closure and modify the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate,  displayedComponents:.date {
     Text("Hallo")
      .font(.largeTitle)
}
```

You can pass the text label as closure and modify the Text view as you wish.